# How to generate consecutive week range dates for n past weeks

Tags: bash, date, awk

I would like to generate a list of *n* week range dates going backward from the current week, like so

```
2014-03-22 2014-03-28
2014-03-15 2014-03-21
2014-03-08 2014-03-14
etc.
```

where the first date in each row is the beginning of the weekly period, which starts Saturday and ends Friday.

My preference would be to do this in a shell script, using awk or other Unix tools. The field delimiter doesn't matter, but the records should be one per line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n=5    
for i in $(seq 0 $((n-1))); do
    echo "$(date -d "last saturday -$i weeks" +"%Y-%m-%d") $(date -d "friday -$i weeks" +"%Y-%m-%d")"; 
done
```

Output:

```
2014-03-22 2014-03-28
2014-03-15 2014-03-21
2014-03-08 2014-03-14
2014-03-01 2014-03-07
2014-02-22 2014-02-28
```

Comment: whoa...I had no idea you could do that with date.  really cool.

Comment: POSIX date doesn't have the -d --date=STRING feature. Is it hard to adapt your script so it doesn't use GNU's --date=STRING?

Comment: Yes, the script above relies heavily on being able to use that feature I'm afraid. I think `awk` may be your best bet, unless you want to follow @Anthony's suggestion and use a lot of shell arithmetic.

Comment: It's OK I can install gnu date on OS X via homebrew coreutils

Comment: Good one! Note you are using `last saturday` and `friday`. Depending on the day of the week you are, it could give some problems. I would upvote... but already did yesterday :)

Comment: Hm.. I think the only issue would be when the date was Saturday? Fixable by doing something like `last=""; [ "$(date +%a)" == "Sat" ] && last="last"`, then using `"$last"` instead of "last" in the date command.

Answer (score 3):

If GNU date is a problem, how about Perl? This should use only standard modules, for a recent-ish version of Perl

```
use v5.10;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

$, = " ";

# get the previous saturday, unless today is saturday
my $day = localtime;
$day -= $day->wday * ONE_DAY unless $day->wday == 6;

while (1) {
    say $day->strftime("%F"), ($day + 6*ONE_DAY)->strftime("%F"); 
    $day -= 7 * ONE_DAY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this using the time in seconds from epoch.

```
date +%s
```

Will show you the current number of seconds elapsed since epoch (Jan 1 1970).

Look at the current day of the week and date, subtract 86400 (number of seconds in a day) * X number of days to get to the previous Saturday.

Print that number in seconds (we'll call it 'foo') using output/format modifiers in the 'date' command, print (foo + 86400*7) for the next coming Friday (March 28).

Then printing prior weeks for N number of weeks is a matter of math (applying -86400 or 7*-86400 to your updated time elapsed since epoch).

There is probably a better way but the first thing I thought of if you wish to use shell.